# Infobox still flowing off view Bing Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, bing-maps, infobox

I was trying to make it so that when a user clicks on a pin on the map it centers on that pin but if the infobox is too tall and goes off the view then it will readjust to offset for the portion off the map.  This is the code but doesn't seem to work correctly every time.  Certain infoboxes are still flowing off screen and dy is alerting back 0.  So here is the code:

```
//Displaying and hiding infobox
function displayInfobox(e) {
    if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
        infobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
        infobox.setOptions({
            visible: true,
            title: e.target.Title,
            description: e.target.htmlContent,
            width: 250,
            offset: new MM.Point(-3, 0)
        });
        //centering map on pushpin
        var pinLocation = e.target.getLocation();

        map.setView({
            center: pinLocation
        });


        infoBoxOrigHeight = $('.Infobox').outerHeight();
        infoBoxHeight = $('.Infobox .infobox-body').outerHeight();

        var stalkHeight = $('.infobox-stalk').outerHeight();

        var newOffset = (infoBoxHeight - infoBoxOrigHeight) + stalkHeight;

        $('.Infobox').css({
            'height': infoBoxHeight,
                'top': -newOffset
        });


        $('.Infobox').css('height', infoBoxHeight);

        $('.infobox-stalk').css('top', infoBoxHeight);


        var buffer = 100;
        var infoboxOffset = infobox.getOffset();
        var infoboxAnchor = infobox.getAnchor();
        var infoboxLocation = map.tryLocationToPixel(e.target.getLocation(), Microsoft.Maps.PixelReference.control);
        var dx = infoboxLocation.x + infoboxOffset.x - infoboxAnchor.x;
        var dy = infoboxLocation.y - 100 - infoboxAnchor.y;

        if (dy < buffer) { //Infobox overlaps with top of map.
            //Offset in opposite direction.
            dy *= -1;
            //add buffer from the top edge of the map.
            dy += buffer;
        } else {
            //If dy is greater than zero than it does not overlap.
            dy = 0;
        }

        if (dx < buffer) { //Check to see if overlapping with left side of map.
            //Offset in opposite direction.
            dx *= -1;
            //add a buffer from the left edge of the map.
            dx += buffer;

        } else { //Check to see if overlapping with right side of map.
            dx = map.getWidth() - infoboxLocation.x + infoboxAnchor.x - infobox.getWidth();
            //If dx is greater than zero then it does not overlap.
            if (dx > buffer) {
                dx = 0;
            } else {
                //add a buffer from the right edge of the map.
                dx -= buffer;
            }
        }
        //Adjust the map so infobox is in view
        alert('dx: ' + dx + ' dy: ' + dy);
        if (dx != 0 || dy != 0) {
            map.setView({
                centerOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(dx, dy),
                center: map.getCenter()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Just wondering what I am implementing wrong that this is not working as it should?

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bing maps module exactly for that. You can check it [here](http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2013/07/bing-maps-module-infoboxautopan.html). You can check a usage example [here](http://psousa.net/demos/bingmaps/infoBoxAutoPanModule/simpleExample.html).

Here's the relevant code of the module:

```
var infobox = this;
var mapWidth = _map.getWidth();
var mapHeight = _map.getHeight();

var point = _map.tryLocationToPixel(infobox.getLocation());

var remainderX = (mapWidth / 2) - point.x;
var remainderY = (mapHeight / 2) + point.y;

//Empirical values based on the current infobox implementation
var xExtraOffset = 33;
var yExtraOffset = 37;

var pixelsOutsideX = infobox.getWidth() + infobox.getOffset().x - remainderX - xExtraOffset + _options.horizontalPadding;
var pixelsOutsideY = infobox.getHeight() + infobox.getOffset().y + yExtraOffset - remainderY + _options.verticalPadding;

var newPoint = new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 0);

if (pixelsOutsideX > 0) {
    newPoint.x += pixelsOutsideX;
}

if (pixelsOutsideY > 0) {
    newPoint.y -= pixelsOutsideY;
}

var newLocation = _map.tryPixelToLocation(newPoint);

_map.setView({
    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(newLocation.latitude, newLocation.longitude)
});
```

Comment: Will this work even if the map is re-sizable?  I can't implement it at the moment but thought I would ask.

Comment: It should. I fetch the current map size before panning the view.

Comment: So after using your module, when running it keeps on saying arguments is undefined on this line `if(arguments.autoPan == true && arguments.visible == true) {`  Any tips to help with this?

Comment: I have been trying to implement your solution but still getting the arguments is undefined.  What are some reasons this could be?

Comment: Not sure. Just grab the example I've placed on http://psousa.net/demos/bingmaps/infoBoxAutoPanModule/simpleExample.html and change it from there. It's just 1 HTML and 1 js file

Comment: I eventually did get it past the undefined problem it was had something to do with there not being any options set on the infobox in a previously line and so had to add options to it.  But since then we have moved away from using the module and have now limited the size of the infobox and centering the map on the selected pin.  So no need for the adjustment now.  Thanks though.